# Returned Promise of mdDialog does not work

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-material

Seems like my mdDialog popup doesn't work the way it should.

```
function () {
    $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: 'CameraPopup.html',
        clickOutsideToClose: true      
    }).then(function (answer){ //do something 

                               //with answer
})}
```

The template looks like this:

```
<md-dialog >
<form>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="column" >
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button ng-click="answer('camera')">
            Open Camera
        </md-button>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        <md-button ng-click="answer('gallery')">
            Open Gallery
        </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</form></md-dialog>
```

I know the problem lies in the promise it returns, but I can't figure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one controller. Pass that controller into `$mdDialog.show`. Write `answer` method into controller.

```
function () {
       $mdDialog.show({
             controller: DialogController,
             templateUrl: 'CameraPopup.html',
             clickOutsideToClose: true      
          }).then(function (answer){ //do something with answer
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
      $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
  }
});
```